# How to Secure Laravel API (sanctum)

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a laravel application with a login system, only for interns
and
I have a Website which gets and posts data from/to the laravel application with a api

So i want, that only my website can get/post data from/to the api -> laravel app

For now, i've created a login user for the api with email and password. I know thats not the right way to do it.

And with this login credentials the website gets a bearer token from the api (expiration 10 min)

With this bearer token (header of ajax call) the website calls every api request (get/post)

### Code:

**Ajax call to get Bearer Token:**

```
 axios.post(data_source_url + "/auth/token", {'email' : 'api@email.de', 'password' : 'pw1'}).then((res) => {
        document.cookie = 'bearer=' + res.data + ';expires=' ...
    })
```

Laravel Api Routes:

```
Route::post('/auth/token', ['uses'=>'ApiController@getToken'])->name('api.getToken');
Route::get('/get', ['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum', 'uses'=>'Api\ApiController@read']);
Route::post('/send', ['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum', 'uses'=>'Api\ApiController@send']);
```

so I would like to leave it that way with authorise with a bearer token, but how to send and receive a bearer token from the api the right/**secure** way, because the way i do it right now with the login is totally insecure

Answer (score 1):

You should not leave open your route to get the token. I've written an article in this matter [Laravel 8 REST API](https://marcelozarate.com/laravel-8-rest-api-with-sanctum)
This approach lets you get a token by first logging in with a valid user to the app. For your use case, you just remove the register route and controller, and you will be able to secure it just for your use.

Route

```
Route::post('/login', [ApiController::class, 'login']);
```

Controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
     if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
     return response()->json(['message' => 'Incorrect e-mail or password'], 401);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

    $token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
    ]);
}
```

I just realized you are logging in to retrieve the bearer. Relax, headers are encrypted using HTTPS, so it is secure as far as I know.

In order to remove the plaintext user and password in the js call, you need to install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) by issuing `npm install dotenv --save`

Now add to your .env file

```
MY_API_USER=api@email.de
MY_API_PASSWORD=pw1
```

Then you need to add to your file

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

So you can use the sensitive data this way

```
axios.post(data_source_url + "/auth/token", {'email' : process.env.MY_API_USER, 'password' : process.env.MY_API_USER}).then((res) => {
    document.cookie = 'bearer=' + res.data + ';expires=' ...
})
```

You won't share your .env file, and be sure to add it to your `.gitignore` or similar, if it is not there.

Comment: yes i know that the header is encryptetd, but everyone can read my .js file and get the email and password

Comment: Oh, that is simply solved by using dotenv and storing your sensitive data in your .env file https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration

Comment: i mean the ajax call to my laravel app. the website is vanilla html/javascript

Comment: Sorry, it's too early in here. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv You need to `require('dotenv').config()` then you can retrieve your data with `process.env.MY_API_USER` and `process.env.MY_API_PASSWORD`